# What is the correct jdbc for Spring boot for containerized postgressql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a Spring boot app that is containerized and published to the docker hub. I have this docker-copmse.yml:-

```
version: '3.1'
services:

postgres:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_DB=mydb

profile_back:
  container_name: profile_back
  image: madsum/profile_back
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
    - postgres
```

My spring boot application.propertiese:-

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I don't know what is the correct spring.datasource.url. I tried both `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb` and `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/mydb` .Both give connection error. Btw,  container runs perfectly. I can verify by it as `docker exec  -it --user postgres dbpostgresql sh` . I can see the database created. What is the correct way to connect it?

**Updated question:-**

I am using flyway. Here is the exception now:-

> ound 1 JPA repository interfaces.
>   2020-03-06 09:33:01.939  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
>   2020-03-06 09:33:01.949  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
>   2020-03-06 09:33:01.949  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
>   2020-03-06 09:33:01.997  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
>   2020-03-06 09:33:01.998  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1180 ms
>   2020-03-06 09:33:02.118  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 6.0.8 by Redgate
>   2020-03-06 09:33:02.124  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
>   2020-03-06 09:33:02.127  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
>   2020-03-06 09:33:02.130  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2020-03-06 09:33:02.141  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2020-03-06 09:33:02.145 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]

Comment: I have added an answer below but if  that does not work please post more details like `what is the spring boot version`, and the `exception you were getting when connecting to DB `and any other details you think might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully reading the exception, gives you a valuable hint:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not
>   accept jdbcUrl,
>   jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE 2020-03-06

So it seems your application tries to connect to an in-memory H2 database and not to PostgreSQL.

Do you maybe use different profiles for your application and forgot to set the *production* profile? Otherwise, you can get rid of the H2 dependency in your `pom.xml`/`build.gradle` if you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost